# Scala Play JSON Type conversion

Tags: scala, type-conversion, avro, play-json

I'm currently struggling with the type conversion of the Play! Json library for Scala...
I have data that looks like this:

```
val myJson = Json.parse(...)

val mapping = Map[String, Option(JsValue)](
    "id" -> (myJson \ "Path" \ stringValue),
    "num" -> (myJson \ "Path" \ intValue),
    "precision" -> (myJson \ "Path" \ "floatValue")
)
```

Also, I have an Avro Schema that defines the data types of each field, in this case it's:
- id: String
- num: Int
- precision: Float

If I now iterate over the fields and check the types against the Avro Schema like this (Note that field in this case is the name of the value to get, e.g. "id"):

```
    ...
    case Schema.Type.STRING => mapping.getOrElse(field, None) match {
      case Some(stringVal: JsValue) => stringVal.as[String]
      case None => null
    }
    case Schema.Type.INT => mapping.getOrElse(field, None) match {
      case Some(intVal) => intVal.as[Int]
      case None => null
    }
    case Schema.Type.FLOAT => mapping.getOrElse(field, None) match {
      case Some(floatVal) => floatVal.as[Float]
      case None => null
    }
    ...
```

I always get this Error:

```
[org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread]  - Streams application error during processing in thread [StreamThread-1]:play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))))
```

(Note: of course the error.expected.jsnumber can also be jsstring sometimes)

Here are the ways of conversion that I already tried, and did not work (I have several different of the mappings that in the end still contain either None or a value of given type):

```
floatVal.as[Float]
floatVal.as[JsNumber].as[Float]
floatVal.as[JsNumber].value.toFloat
Hi,
```

I'm currently struggling with the type conversion of the Play! Json library for Scala...
I have data that looks like this:

```
val myJson = Json.parse(...)

val mapping = Map[String, Option(JsValue)](
    "id" -> (myJson \ "Path" \ stringValue),
    "num" -> (myJson \ "Path" \ intValue),
    "precision" -> (myJson \ "Path" \ "floatValue")
)
```

Also, I have an Avro Schema that defines the data types of each field, in this case it's:
- id: String
- num: Int
- precision: Float

If I now iterate over the fields and check the types against the Avro Schema like this (Note that field in this case is the name of the value to get, e.g. "id"):

```
    ...
    case Schema.Type.STRING => mapping.getOrElse(field, None) match {
      case Some(stringVal: JsValue) => stringVal.as[String]
      case None => null
    }
    case Schema.Type.INT => mapping.getOrElse(field, None) match {
      case Some(intVal) => intVal.as[Int]
      case None => null
    }
    case Schema.Type.FLOAT => mapping.getOrElse(field, None) match {
      case Some(floatVal) => floatVal.as[Float]
      case None => null
    }
    ...
```

I always get this Error:

```
[org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread]  - Streams application error during processing in thread [StreamThread-1]:play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsnumber),WrappedArray())))))
```

(Note: of course the error.expected.jsnumber can also be jsstring sometimes)

Here are the ways of conversion that I already tried, and did not work (I have several different of the mappings that in the end still contain either None or a value of given type):

```
floatVal.as[Float]
floatVal.as[JsNumber].as[Float]
floatVal.as[JsNumber].value.toFloat
floatVal.as[String].value.toFloat
floatVal.as[JsString].value.toString.toFloat
floatVal.as[String].toFloat
floatVal.as[String].value.toFloat
floatVal.as[JsString].value.toString.toFloat
floatVal.as[JsString].as[String].toFloat
floatVal.as[JsString].as[String].value.toFloat
floatVal.as[JsString].as[String].value.toString.toFloat
```

Somehow I have problems for all the types, only in some cases, but I have them...
What is also interesting is, that even though the type is `JsValue`, when I look at them with the Debugger, the type says `Js<type>`, e.g. `JsString` instead of `JsValue`.
In some occasions, however not always, it also displays `JsString` for the Int type...

Why doesn't it keep them as `JsValue`?

What is the right way to convert the Play! Json types?

Thank you
All the best
Tim

Comment: Try to focused on a minimal reproducer. There the question is quite broad

Comment: @cchantep Can you give me a hint where I should specify the question further? In general the question is simply about how to handle conversion when the play framework implicitly converts `Int` values to a `JsString` value which throws an error when I want to convert it into a real `Int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just making sure to update with the way that worked for me.

In my case I just did the `JsString`, `JsNumber`, ... conversion right away on my own so that the framework is not inferring the type of it on it's own.